# Insert from tempt table where SEQ_NUM <> 2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am trying to do an insert in the below table `PS_VNDR_ADDR_SCROL`  from data in a temp table where there is not already a row in the table being inserted `PS_VNDR_ADDR_SCROL` that has a `SEQ_NUM` equal to `2` for the same `VENDOR_ID`.

The below SQL runs but does not insert any rows, and I know there should be 132 records that meet this condition.

```
INSERT PS_VNDR_ADDR_SCROL 
SELECT 'SHARE', A.VENDOR_ID, 2, 'HOME', 'BUSN', ''
FROM #DepWork2 A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT VENDOR_ID 
    FROM PS_VNDR_ADDR_SCROL B 
    WHERE B.VENDOR_ID = A.VENDOR_ID AND SEQ_NUM <> 2
)
```

I've also tried this using `NOT IN` as follows, but I get a syntax error:

```
INSERT PS_VNDR_ADDR_SCROL 
SELECT 'SHARE', A.VENDOR_ID, 2, 'HOME', 'BUSN', ''
FROM #DepWork2 A
WHERE NOT IN (
    SELECT VENDOR_ID 
    FROM PS_VNDR_ADDR_SCROL B 
    WHERE B.VENDOR_ID = A.VENDOR_ID AND SEQ_NUM <> 2
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> insert in the below table `PS_VNDR_ADDR_SCROL` [...] where there is **not** already a row in the table [...] `PS_VNDR_ADDR_SCROL` that has a `SEQ_NUM` equal to 2 for the same `VENDOR_ID`

Your approach using `NOT EXISTS` looks fine, however I think that, to conform to your spec, the correlated subquery should be spelled:

```
SELECT VENDOR_ID 
FROM PS_VNDR_ADDR_SCROL B 
WHERE B.VENDOR_ID = A.VENDOR_ID AND SEQ_NUM = 2
```

Instead of:

```
SELECT VENDOR_ID 
FROM PS_VNDR_ADDR_SCROL B 
WHERE B.VENDOR_ID = A.VENDOR_ID AND SEQ_NUM <> 2
```

Hence, try:

```
INSERT PS_VNDR_ADDR_SCROL 
SELECT 
    'SHARE', 
    A.VENDOR_ID, 
    2, 
    'HOME', 
    'BUSN', 
    ''
FROM #DepWork2 A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM PS_VNDR_ADDR_SCROL B 
    WHERE B.VENDOR_ID = A.VENDOR_ID AND SEQ_NUM = 2
)
```

---

NB: the syntax error in the second query comes from this part of the SQL code:

```
...
WHERE NOT IN (
    SELECT VENDOR_ID 
    ...
)
```

You need to specify a column on the left side of the `NOT IN` condition. This should probably be:

```
...
WHERE A.VENDOR_ID NOT IN (
    SELECT VENDOR_ID 
    ...
)
```

NB: of course, the second query should also have condition `SEQ_NUM = 2` instead of `SEQ_NUM <> 2` in the correlated subquery.

Comment: Using `NOT EXISTS` with `SEQ_NBR = 2` worked as expected, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try by using exists

```
INSERT PS_VNDR_ADDR_SCROL 
SELECT 'SHARE', A.VENDOR_ID, 2, 'HOME', 'BUSN', ''
FROM #DepWork2 A
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1  FROM PS_VNDR_ADDR_SCROL B  WHERE B.VENDOR_ID = A.VENDOR_ID AND SEQ_NUM = 2)
```

Comment: If I change it to `WHERE EXISTS` then I get a duplicate key insert error.